# Jquery Reload DOM before return

Tags: jquery, recursion

I want to moves a `<div>` down the page slowly. My idea was to use jquery to change it's  `margin-top` value.

But Jquery isn't updating the page and instead waiting for the function to return, before making the div move. 
My Code:

```
function move(x) {
    if(x == 0){
        return;
    }
    var top = parseFloat($("#mydiv").css("margin-top"));
    $("#mydiv").html(x);
    $("#mydiv").css("margin-top", (top + 10).toString() + "px");
    return move(x-1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2035/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
waiting for the function to return, before making the div
```

^-- JavaScript is asynchronous, it'll not wait for a function to return (*Unless you make it work the otherway somehow*)

You can do dirty tricks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2038/), But what you're probably looking for is jQueries [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function which gives you way better control.

Modify your function as follows:

```
function move(x) {
 $("#mydiv").animate({
    'margin-top': x
 })
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2037/)

You can also look into css  transitions like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2039/).

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/qYdwR/2036/)

```
$(function() {
    move(20);
});
```